# Matrix Differentiation of Generative Neural Network

Tags: derivatives, optimization, matrix-calculus, neural-networks

I wish to construct a neural network (restricted Boltzmann Machine) with network parameter set $\Omega$ that will minimise the cost function,
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{C}(\Omega) = -\text{Tr}\big[A\log(B_\Omega)\big] 
\end{equation}
where $B_\Omega$ is a Hermitian, postive semi-definite matrix generated by the neural network, and $A$ is a fixed Hermitian, postive semi-definite matrix.

Due to the $\log(\cdot)$, this appears very tricky. How do I take derivates of this cost function with respect to an arbitrary parameter $\Omega_i$ of the network? Is this out of reach analytically and perhaps automatic differentiation is a better approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Differentiating the matrix logarithm is a big challenge, but there are a couple of approaches at your disposal that could be useful.  One lemma comes from [a paper by Moakher](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis610/geomean.pdf) in which the derivative of a single-variable matrix function $X(t)$ [as long as $X$ is invertible with positive eigenvalues] has the following form:

> Let $X(t)$ be a real matrix-valued function of the real variable $t$.
>   We assume that, for all $t$ in its domain, $X(t)$ is an invertible
>   matrix which does not have eigenvalues on the closed negative real
>   line. Then. $$ \frac{d}{dt} \frac{1}{2}\text{Tr} \left
>  (\text{Log}^2(X(t)) \right ) \;\; =\;\; \text{Tr}\left
>  (\text{Log}(X(t)) \cdot X^{-1}(t) \cdot \dot{X}(t)\right ). $$

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be your objective function that you're working with.  Another way around this would be to truncate your logarithm to some Taylor expansion.  I imagine this would be warranted since you're dealing with an algorithm and a closed-form expression may not be necessary for your applications.  Using
$$
\text{Log}(X) \;\; =\;\; \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} (X - I)^k \;\; =\;\; (X-I) - \frac{1}{2}(X-I)^2 + \frac{1}{3}(X-I)^3 + \ldots 
$$

Your objective function can be rewritten as

$$
-\text{Tr}\left (A\text{Log}(B_\Omega)\right ) \;\; =\;\; \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k} \text{Tr}\left [A (B_\Omega - I)^k\right ].
$$

The one issue here is that the logarithm is only guaranteed to converge absolutely if $||B_\Omega|| < 1$, but for the sake of computation you can truncate this series expansion to whatever precision you want/need and take derivatives with respect to these terms instead.